# Way to revert Chinese/Korean text converted to seemingly random characters in Excel sheet

Tags: character, converters, revert

I recently received a spreadsheet from a coworker with a global listing of articles associated with some key metrics we are tracking.

Unfortunately, all titles that were in Chinese or Korean were somewhere converted to seemingly random characters (see below) by the system (custom, internally built) that metrics are pulled from.

Long term, I will need to get the system fixed, but in the short term I was wondering if there was any way to revert what I'm seeing back to the respective correct characters.

Doing some manual matching for the ones that had some English in the title:

1. 가족과 함께 보내는 특별한 하루 becomes ê°€ì¡±ê³¼-í•¨ê»˜-ë³´ë‚´ëŠ”-íŠ¹ë³„í•œ-í•˜ë£¨-â€“-â€œ
2. 城市生活美學公益講座 becomes ä¸–ç•Œé–±è®€æ—¥-â€“-è¬›åº§å ±å°Ž

Any idea what I'm looking at here?

Comment: Is the answer for this question not in the internally built custom system that produced the metrics?

Comment: Looks Excel is loading the file with a different encoding, or the file was not saved with the proper character set. Try forcing Unicode to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Marvelo, that was it! Forcing Unicode got the characters to show up correctly in the Excel sheet.